# Can I use have+nominal+verb as a fact (simple present)?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

I have read these two: [strange-used-to-have-object-of-subsequent-p-p-structure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/335585/strange-used-to-have-object-of-subsequent-p-p-structure) and [have-noun-verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97647/have-noun-verb). What I got from there (at least, when they -answerers- give examples) is, the form (as in the title) is commonly used in the past tense.

My question is, can I use that form as a fact? I mean like something true or indisputable. For instance:

> People always have their old-fashioned notions debunked when there is
> a new trustable theory promulgated.

My reason I'm asking whether that sentence above grammatically acceptable is because what I've understood so far, the form above is only used in the past.

And please, I need your correction about my highlighted sentence above if I've made mistakes. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighted sentence describes something that happens habitually or repeatedly, and doesn't need to be in past tense.

> I have my laundry done whenever it gets dirty.

If it is your sentence, it seems alright grammatically. It seems harder to read because of the structure, though. The same thought might be expressed by leaving out the reference to people.

> Old-fashioned notions get debunked when...